# Xpath replacement / Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I have managed to perform the click operation with the following :

```
chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='button button-primary cookie-accept-all']")).click();
```

I did the investigation and found out that it is not recommended to use xpath and much better to refer to css.

How can i possible do the same i did above with `@FindBy(className = )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you can try something like this (not tested):

```
chromeDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".button .button-primary .cookie-accept-all']")).click();
```

But please check the documentation that is quite useful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: try with less selectors

Comment: this worked >         chromeDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".cookie-accept-all")).click();

Comment: as a general advice, use developer tools of your browser to troubleshoot this stuff. You can copy the selector from there and also use the console to test your expressions.